# is the following sequence equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, equicontinuity

Let $f_k(x) = \frac{e^{-kx}}{k^2}$ where $x \in [0, 1]$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Is this sequence equicontinuous? What if $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

The definition I have been given is:
Let $F$ be a subset of $\mathscr{F}(X;Y)$, functions from metric space $(X, d_X)$ to $(Y, d_Y)$. We say $F$ is equicontinuous if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $d_X(x, y) < \delta$, for $x, y \in X$, we have $d_Y(f(x), f(y)) < \epsilon$ for all $f \in \mathscr{F}$.

I have tried arranging $|f_k(x) - f_k(y)| < \epsilon$ to something contianing $|x-y|$ but I am not yet successful. Any hints would be great.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/148510). Some context and effort is necessary. As you can see someone has downvoted.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you talking about pointwise equicontinuity or uniform equicontinuity? Please add your thoughts, definitions you know that are relevant to the problem, etc. to get constructive help from the community.

Comment: That's an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$|f_k(x) - f_k(y)| = \left|f_k'(\xi)(x-y) \right|= \frac{ke^{-k\xi}}{k^2}|x-y|, \quad \xi \in (x,y)$$